# Vue component library without packing the supporting packages or compiling scss files

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, vue-component

I am tasked with figuring out how to publish a component library my team is working on. These components will be consumed by various internal applications within the company. I have the following constraints:

- The library will be consumed as an npm package from internal local
  repository. (this part I have figured out)
- Components should be
  compiled to JavaScript with typescript interface (*.d.ts) references
  within the package.
- No third-party packages (including Vue) should
  be bundled in. Rather, it’s desirable to have the dependent npm
  packages added to a project when the component is added and after `npm i`.
- The compiled css bundle should be included with the package but
  should be referenced separately within a project when it’s needed.
- The raw scss files that make up the component styles should be
  included with the package so they can be bundled into a project’s
  existing scss during a build.

I’ve looked into `vue-cli-service build --target lib` to accomplish this, but it seems that it bundles and packs everything up.

Is what I’m asking even possible? Is it an anti-pattern? Are there alternatives? I don’t know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You've headed in the right direction with `vue-cli-service build --target lib` this is exactly what you need. It bundles your entry `.vue` file as a component then this bundle becomes your entry point for `package.json`. It doesn't include the Vue library in it (this is stated in the docs) and I think that by default it's configured to [extract the CSS](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract) in a separate file in `dist` folder.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Nikolay, thanks for your response!
Doesn't --target- lib also bundle dependent npm packages as well?

Comment: Yes, it does, all installed packages in `dependencies` are internal dependencies and it extracts (treeshakes) the needed code from them and then adds it in the final bundle. Maybe Webpack can be configured to treat some of the dependencies as external dependencies.

Comment: Bummer. That's the opposite of what I want :(
I need to compose my typescript into javascript without including dependent libraries. Instead, I'd like to reference the dependencies in the package.json file that comes with the deployed package.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, I haven't tried it yet, but it seems like what we need -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571579/vuejs-library-cli-v3-exclude

I also need something like this for some of my components.

Comment: This has been de-prioritized so I won't be able to continue with it until next sprint. Expect to hear from me in a couple of weeks with any results.

Comment: Good luck, if I find something about this I'll share too.